# Caracter opcional para validar cadena con lookbehind

Tags: javascript, nodejs, regex, discord.js

Quiero validar una cadena que el inicio pueda escribirse de manera diferente.

Quiero dar como entrada una cadena `hjoin` o `h!join` y que en ambos casos seleccione solamente `join`.

He intentado hacer esto con la expresión `/(?<=^h!?).+/gi`.

Aquí estoy usando `!?` para hacer el signo de exclamación opcional en la cadena, el detalle es que en la cadena `hjoin` no hay problema, el problema es con `h!join` porque a pesar de que tiene el signo opcional, el resultado es que selecciona `!join`.

¿Hay algo que pueda hacer al respecto con esto?

**Edición**: Olvidé mencionar un detalle que ahora sé que es importante, necesito que la expresión solamente aplique para el inicio tal que el resto de la cadena pueda contener necesariamente cualquier caracter, no solamente palabras.

Comment: intenta con: (?<=h|!h).+?\b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claro que `/(?<=^h!?).+/i` va a coincidir con `!join` dentro de `"h!join"`, porque es la primera posición en el texto que satisface al regex (está precedido por "h").

Podrías arreglarlo con `/(?<=^h(?:(?!!)|!)).+/i` para garantizar que si está precedido por `h`, esa posición no esté seguida de `!`, **o** garantizar que esté precedido por `h!`.

Sin embargo, te estás complicando la existencia con el lookbehind, es totalmente innecesario. Para eso están los paréntesis (grupos), que capturan el texto que coincidió con esa parte del regex.

```
/^h!?(.+)/i
```

```js
const regex = /^h!?(.+)/i;
const str = 'h!join';
let m;

if ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    console.log('Todo el regex coincidió con', m[0], 'pero lo que nos importa es el primer grupo, que coincidió con', m[1]);
}
```

Comment: Sí, creo que me estaba complicando, por ahora estaba usando más código para este problema, pero mi objetivo, precisamente, era usar menos código usando una expresión regular más completa.
No sé mucho de `.exec`, pero hasta donde he leído creo que entiendo lo que pasa, ¿El parámetro `[1]` te da ese resultado porque en la expresión regular está entre paréntesis esa parte?
Donde he leído dice que `.exec` tarda más en ejecutarse que otros métodos de expresiones regulares, ¿No es mejor utilizar la expresión regular larga?

Answer (score -1):

Utiliza el `lookbehind` (ver atrás) con la siguiente expresión:

```
(?<=h|h!)join
```

Seleccionará solo `join` si y solo si le precede  una `h`oi `h!`.

Actualización:

Para cualquier palabra luego de  `h` o `h!`:

```
(?<=h!|h)\w+
```

**Actualización 2:**

Si bien fue aceptada, y me parece correcta la respuesta, no quisiera dejar a medias la expresión que propuse puesto que pensé que era la primera palabra o la constante "join".

Continuando con la expresión  `lookbehind` la siguiente cadena captura todo lo que se encuentra luego de `h` o `h!`:

```
(?<=h|h!)\w.*
```

```
const regex = /(?<=^h|^h!)\w.*/g;
const str = 'h!join y demas palabras...!';

let m = str.match(regex); // retorna un arreglo
if(m){
 console.log(m); // ["join y demas palabras...!"]
 console.log(m[0]); // "join y demas palabras...!"
}
```

Cabe señalar que la condición de esta expresión es que luego de la condición venga una letra o número.

Comment: Así como esta eso funciona, el detalle es que necesito que sea para cualquiera que sea el contenido que siga, no solamente es join sino también más palabras.

Comment: Por eso intento usar `.+` para seleccionar lo que siga del lookbehind, pero por agregar eso la expresión selecciona el signo `!`.

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta

Comment: Funciona pero solamente para la siguiente palabra escrita, lo que busco es que seleccione más de una palabra y además pueda capturar caracteres especiales también.